# SQL: How to select only the oldest record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realize this is a question that has been asked previously but upon investigating those posts, none of them fit exactly what I'm working on.

I have a list of people who have visited a location, many of which have visited multiple times. Each person has a unique ID, and each visit has a date and a status (I'm looking only at visits with a status of 'unchanged,' as opposed to 'canceled,' 'rescheduled,' etc.). What I need to be able to do is select only the oldest record for each person. In other words, see only the date of their very first visit.

I've solved a problem like this before and I went back and found my old code and attempted to apply it to this particular situation. The issue is that back then, I was trying to pull the most *recent* record for a given person, and I'm not sure how to change what I have here to apply to the *oldest* record. If one person has had 3 visits and another has had 7, I don't know what to do with my `seqnum` variable.

Also, if I run this code below the way it currently is, I'm still getting multiple records for each person, which is another problem entirely. At least the filter for unchanged visits is working.

Any thoughts?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PersonID,
  PersonName,
  VisitDate,
  Status,
  VisitType

FROM (SELECT VisitInfo.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, VisitDate ORDER BY VisitDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM VisitInfo
      WHERE Status = 'Unchanged'

      ) VisitInfo

WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY VisitDate
```

Comment: Have you tried a `GROUP BY` with `MIN` on date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't partition by `VisitDate`, because of it almost each row has its own partition.

```
SELECT 
  PersonID,
  PersonName,
  VisitDate,
  Status,
  VisitType

FROM (SELECT VisitInfo.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY VisitDate) as seqnum
      FROM VisitInfo
      WHERE Status = 'Unchanged'

      ) VisitInfo

WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY VisitDate
```

Comment: Correct, as far as eliminating duplicates, but to solve the immediate problem of getting the oldest row instead of the newest, you'll want to change the `ORDER BY VisitDate` from `DESC` to `ASC`, or just delete the `DESC` since ascending is the default.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I was just about to say that this code solved the duplicate problem but wasn't pulling the oldest record. But changing the ORDER BY part seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I like your attempt and M. Kanarkowski's solution, but here is another alternative.

```
SELECT     a.PersonID
         , a.PersonName
         , a.VisitDate
         , a.Status
         , a.VisitType
FROM       VisitInfo AS a
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT PersonID
                    , MIN(VisitDate) AS OldestVisitDate
               FROM   VisitInfo
               WHERE  Status = 'Unchanged'
           )         AS b ON a.PersonID = b.PersonID
                             AND a.VisitDate = b.OldestVisitDate
WHERE      a.Status = 'Unchanged';
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      PersonID,
      PersonName,
      MIN(VisitDate) AS [First visit date],          
      VisitType    
FROM 
    VisitInfo
WHERE 
    Status = 'Unchanged'
GROUP BY
    PersonID,
    PersonName,        
    VisitType
```

Not tested!